# Problems in searching records from mongodb node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to search my mongodb database and get the columns that contains the search key. However, when I run my program, its brings all the columns. What could I be doing wrong? My goal is to only return documents in the collection train where trialkey is equal to the value I enter. Not all the documents.

```
app.get('/getdata',function(req,res){
    console.log("Entering here");

    var retrieveapikey = req.query.apiKey;
    console.log("retriever",retrieveapikey);

  /* dbi.collection("trial").find({},{"apikey":retrieveapikey}).toArray(function(err, result) {

        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result.length);

        for(var i=0;i<result.length;i++){
            delete result[i]._id;
        }


        console.log(typeof (result));
        res.send(result);
        //dbi.close();
    });*/

    dbi.collection("trial").find({},{"apikey":retrieveapikey}).toArray(function(err, result) {
     console.log(result);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 dbi.collection("trial").find({}, {"apikey":retrieveapikey})
```

That will find every document and will only return the apikey. You want to do:

```
dbi.collection("trial").find({apikey: retrieveapikey})
```